# How to make a service can access via the service proxy running at the master in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How to  make a service  can access  via the service proxy running at the master  in kubernetes ?
like service of kube-ui or fluentd-elasticsearch in example. can access the url: http://[masterIP:post]/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui/

I can not access http://[masterIP:post]/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/test/services/myweb, when I create a service in the test namespace named myweb.

So how to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access it from a pod running in the cluster, you're best off just accessing the service directly. Services are made available using DNS within the cluster. If your pod is in the same namespace as the service, you should be able to access it simply using its name, e.g. at `myweb` in this case. If your pod is in a different namespace, you can hit it at pod-name.namespace, e.g. `myweb.test` in this case.

If you're trying to access it from outside the cluster, then you shouldn't need to do anything different than you do for the default services. If you're unable to access it in the same way, it's likely that your service doesn't have any pods backing it, or that those pods aren't working. You can check which pods are backing your service using `kubectl get endpoints myweb --namespace=test`. If that's empty, then you should make sure you've scheduled the pods that are meant to implement the service, and if so, that their labels are correct.

You might find the [documentation on services](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/services.md) useful.